# Android - Search option in custom listview c#

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, listview, xamarin

I have a custom `Listview` containing two `textview` and one `imageview`. The `listview` contains more than 100 rows which makes it more difficult to the user to view and select his items. So i want to add the search option in order to make it easier for the user to directly search for the items he want to select. I have already added an `EditText` above the `ListView` but I don't have any clue what to do next.

**Activity.cs:**

```
ListView mListView;
MyAdapter adapter;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
    mListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listview);
    List<TableList> list = new List<TableList>();
    EditText search = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.searchList);
    list.Add(new TableList("Germany","Europe"));
    list.Add(new TableList("France","Europe"));
    list.Add(new TableList("Finland","Europe"));
    list.Add(new TableList("Germany","Europe"));
    list.Add(new TableList("France","Europe"));
    list.Add(new TableList("Germany","Europe"));
    list.Add(new TableList("France","Europe"));
    list.Add(new TableList("Finland","Europe"));

    adapter = new MyAdapter(this, list);
    mListView.Adapter = adapter;
    mListView.ItemClick += MListView_ItemClick;
}

class MyAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
    Context mContext;
    List<TableList> mitems;
    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<TableList> list)
    {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mitems = list;

    }
    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return mitems.Count;
        }
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem(int position)
    {
        return mitems[position];
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        DataViewHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.CoinList, null, false);
            holder = new DataViewHolder();
            holder.tv = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.CoinName);
            holder.iv = convertView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
            holder.cb = convertView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.cont);
            convertView.Tag = holder;
        }
        else
        {
            holder = convertView.Tag as DataViewHolder;

        }
        holder.cb.Tag = position;

        holder.tv.Text = mitems[position].Name;
        holder.cb.Text = mitems[position].Cont
        holder.iv.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.dapao);
        return convertView;

    }
}

public class DataViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
{
    public ImageView iv { get; set; }
    public TextView tv { get; set; }
    public TextView cb { get; set; }

}
public class TableList : Java.Lang.Object
{
    public TableList(string name, string cont)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Cont = cont;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Cont { get; set; }
}
}
```

So I want the filter to be by the `Name` for example when he writes the letter `F` in the `EditText` the `listview` should shows only `France` and `Finland`. How can I do so ? Please help me.

Comment: I have edited my demo, it will give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You would like to use `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` or `AutoCompleteTextView` instead of `EditText`.

See the difference between them from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884117/difference-between-multiautocompletetextview-and-autocompletetextview).

If you just want to input one country, you can use [`AutoCompleteTextView`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Widget.AutoCompleteTextView/), [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/auto-complete) is the official example.

### update:

I have updated me [demo](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/ListViewCheckBox), below is result:
[image]

Comment: That's not the problem. The problem is the listview. I want only to display in it the searched item. Like if the user searched for `France`, it should ONLY display the row containing France

Comment: Sorry, I have misread you, you want your `ListView` scroll to the `France` or you want your `ListView` only show the `France`?

Comment: What about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456525/how-to-filter-listview-using-getfilter-in-baseadapter)?  `adapter.getFilter().filter(s);` You need custom a Filter for you Adapter.

Comment: And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24771174/8632294) is a example which is more completely.

Comment: I have a small problem, I am getting an error here: `results.Values = resultsValues;`in the `FilterResults PerformFiltering(ICharSequence constraint)` function, the error is:`Cannot implicitly convert type TableList to Java.Lang.Object` ??

Comment: And a `null exception` here: `var arry = results.Values.ToArray<TableList>();`

Comment: I don't have these problems on my phone, has the project run on your phone once?

Comment: `Cannot implicitly convert type TableList to Java.Lang.Object`, your `TableList`   need implement `Java.Lang.Object`. `var arry = results.Values.ToArray<TableList>();` check the value of `results.Values`.